# Usage of "like many a" vs "like that of"

Tags: comparison

Sentence in question:

> Sendak’s career began, **like many an artist**, during his childhood.

I think the sentence should be corrected with

> "Sendak’s career began, **like that of many artists**, during his childhood."

Is my correction wrong?

I don't understand the usage of "like many a"
How is the original sentence correct and where can I learn about the usage of "like many a"?

Can you explain the phrase "like many a"?

Comment: Check [The difference between "many" and "many a...."](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/the-difference-between-many-and-many-a).

Comment: shouldn't the "artists" mentioned in the original sentence be "artists" because we are comparing Sendak's career to the careers of a wide spectrum of artists?

Comment: No. You can't say "many an artists". The "many" handles the plural form, so "artist" can remain singular. I think you would most likely find this form in literary works where the writer wanted it written this way for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user3169 states, it's a special use of the word *many.* In a literary style, *many a [someone in singular]* means *many [someone in plural]*. This said, the sentence *actually* means...

> Sendak’s career began, like *many artists,* during his childhood.

Another example to make it clear:

> *It remained a mystery for many a year = It remained a mystery for many years*

Note that to change from *many a...* to *many...* we need to remove singular and add plural. That is the reason, the sentence in question uses a singular.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the structure "many a" but in different situations. For example, the sentence: "Many students ARE foreigners." is the same as "Many a student IS foreigner."