# What does 'many a pursued man' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

In page of '[nemesis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nemesis#:%7E:text=Many%20a%20pursued%20man%20fell%20before%20his%20nemesis%20in%20the%20streets)' in the *Merriam Webster*, there's such a sentence as follows.

> **Many a pursued man** fell before his nemesis in the streets...

What does 'many a pursued man' mean in this sentence?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [' many a man' meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184871/many-a-man-meaning). Also [Usage of "like many a" vs "like that of"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32414/usage-of-like-many-a-vs-like-that-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the whole sentence can be like

> In the streets, **many men who were pursued** fell before their respective nemeses.

[Wiktionary for 'many a(/an)'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/many_a):

Being one of a large number, each one of many

- Their example:

> Many a crime has being committed in its name: there are some being committed now.

meaning:

> Many crimes have been committed in its name: there are some being committed now.

[Merriam for 'many a/an'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/many%20a%2Fan):

used with a singular noun to refer to a large number of things or people

- Their example:

> Many a man has tried but few men have succeeded.

meaning:

> Many men have tried but few men have succeeded.